# GoogleApiException in Google.Apis.Adexchangebuyer.v13 when calling AdexchangebuyerService.Creatives.List

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client

I am getting this exception when calling LIST with a high number ( > 20 ) creative ids. When calling LIST with about 10 creatives, it works fine, and it takes about 30 s for each call.

Below are the exception details :

```
Google.GoogleApiException was caught HResult=-2146233088 Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Backend Error [500] Errors [ Message[Backend Error] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global] ]

Source=Google.Apis ServiceName=adexchangebuyer StackTrace: at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\test\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 102 InnerException:
```

This is the calling code using Google.Apis.AdExchangeBuyer.v1_3 1.9.0.48: (I also tried it using 1.9.0.51)

```
    var listRequest = this.AdexchangebuyerService.Creatives.List();
    listRequest.MaxResults = 1000;
    listRequest.BuyerCreativeId = new Repeatable<string>(creativeIds ); 
    // creativeIds is IEnumerable<string>; (fails with 20 creative ids, passes with 10)
    var listOfCreatives = listRequest.Execute(); // -- exception thrown here
```

The request captured in fiddler using the client library:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/adexchangebuyer/v1.3/creatives?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&pageToken=mypa‌​getoken&maxResults=1000&buyerCreativeId=i7bhb44u&buyerCreativeId=f5bfbul2 
HTTP/1.1 
User-Agent: AdExchangeBuyer google-api-dotnet-client/1.9.1.12394 (gzip)
```

This is the request using the web interface (https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/buyer-rest/v1.3/creatives/list):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/adexchangebuyer/v1.3/creatives?buyerCreativeId=i7bhb44u&buyerCreativeId=f5bfbul2&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the call is too long and you are kind of getting a timeout. So I would recommend to try one of the following:

1. If you have more than x (in you case 10) items, split it to more than one call. It looks like for 10 items it takes more than 20s, so you can split it, and you will NOT get some sort of timeout.
2. Change the default timeout for a higher number than the default (which I read somewhere that's 100s, but I didn't find it in the official documentation - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). You can do the following:

   ```
   this.AdexchangebuyerService.HttpClient.Timeout = 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200);
   ```

Comment: I am splitting the call, but sometimes I have 5000 creative IDs, and that's resulting in about 500 calls, each taking about 20-30s, not very practical... I noticed that using the web interface to run the list operation, I passed a lot more than 20 creatives and it executed very in about a sec with no errors.

Comment: So you are suggesting that the client library slows you down... It seams weird because it's the response that takes time, right? Does the HTTP request looks the same (using Fiddler or some other tool that captured your request)?

Comment: Feel free to add it to your thread, it will be more readable. Can you also attach how the web interface (Google API explorer?) request looks like? Thanks

Comment: Updated the question and added the web interface request.

Comment: So it looks like the urls are the same, except - &pageToken=mypa‌​getoken&maxResults=1000. What is mypagetoken means, did you fill that out?

Comment: this is because the list api returns results in page/batches, and using it to get to next page of results... will try without it

Comment: You can remove it form the Google API explorer or add it in the client library. Those properties should be available on the request object.

Comment: I noticed that with a high number of creative ids passed, the request becomes POST, could that be related?

Comment: It might, you can change this behavior, by setting the MaxUrlLength property of the initializer to 0. I mean that initializer when you create the service object. Read more - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.1/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Services_1_1BaseClientService_1_1Initializer#aeef7862a8ddc0faff6e8c773c336c171